# Does a App Icon badge from a local notification get overridden from a Push Notification payload badge?

Tags: ios

My app will run in the background for ~10 minutes before the system shuts it down. During this time, if the user receives an event, I handle it using Local Notification to inform the user and display a badge icon. Once the App is no longer running in the background a push notification is sent, but when a push is sent, it overrides the current badge count from the local notification since a payload count is attached with the push.

Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the OS is responsible appending badge numbers from push payload. It simply places whatever count the payload has associated with it.